# How do I access filterrific scope variables directly in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications, filterrific

I'm using Ruby on Rails and I'm trying to access a filterrific scope variable from a 'select' drop down in the view for use in the controller.

Basically, my code looks like this.

```
<%= form_for_filterrific @filter do |c| %>
    <%= c.select(:departments, @filter.select_options[:docs], {}, {style: "width: 140px;"} ) %>
<% end %>
```

Is there a way for me to get the currently selected `doc` option from the drop down and send it to a controller?

Comment: You can't send things from views back into the controller. Once the controller has done its thing it hands off rendering to the view and that's a one-way street. You can only propagate changes in a drop-down to another instance of the controller via AJAX calls for form submissions.

Answer (score 0):

After form was submitted you can get selected option in controller from `params`, something like:

```
params[:filterrific][:departments]
```

In any case try inspect `params` in controller to investigate:

```
puts params.inspect
```